# Convert surround query parser to lucene query

Tags: java, solr, lucene, search-engine, query-parser

**Surround Query Parser**

```
(spot prices) 3w (gulf coast)
```

to

**Lucene Query**

```
("spot"~3 or "prices"~3) or ("gulf"~3 or "coast"~3)
```

Is there easy way convert surround query to lucene query?

Comment: When you say "easy way to convert" - do you mean you are looking for a way to automate the conversion of **any** Surround query to its equivalent Lucene query?

Comment: @andrewjames yes